# How to make green progress operate at normal speed in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, images

One I open folder with images in Windows 10, the green progress appear in address bar (with folder path). It moves to 100% for a few minutes. Until then I can't see file properties in the right pane. Once I cut any file to move to different directory, the process begin again.

How to fix that?

I guess it performs some unneeded operations. How to enlist them and remove unneeded ones?

Answer (score 0):

The "green progress bar" is only an animation the Windows uses to tell the user that it' working. I've never seen it actually related to the duration before the Explorer window become operational.

When you open a folder with images, what happens while that progress bar is filling, is that Explorer is fetching for each file the associated thumbnail, or reading the file to create the thumbnail if it wasn't found.

The easiest (and to my knowledge, only) way to disable that is by switching to a folder view where no thumbnail is displayed, such as List or Details.

Comment: I would like it to build thumbnails. What I don't like is that it build them again and again and/or build them too long.